# Напишите функцию, которая принимает строку и возвращает массив слов

Tags: java

Напишите функцию, которая принимает строку и возвращает массив слов.

Под словом подразумеваются множество символов отличных от пробела. Между словами может стоять больше одного пробела.

Делаю что-то не так - потому что выводит ошибку: [Ljava.lang.String;@
Может кто-нибудь знает где я ошибаюсь....может совсем решение неверное. хотя по логике. вроде получаю слово..

Вот мой код

```
public static String[] split(String s){
        String [] array = s.split(" ");
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            String word = array[i];
        }
        return array;
    }
public static void main(String[] args) {
        String s = "I am learning java";
        System.out.println(split(s));
    }
```

Подскажите пожалуйста, где именно я не верно пишу код
или пишу его не до конца

Текст ошибки: [Ljava.lang.String;@568db2f2

Comment: В чём логика в цикле сохранять каждый элемент массива в локальную переменную, которая нигде не используется и, соответственно, удаляется? Строки 3-5 не имеют смысла.

Comment: Не понятно, что за ошибка. Приведите, пожалуйста, полный текст ошибки и при каком примере вводимых данных она происходит. Желательно, дополнить вопрос через редактирование.

Comment: Отредактировала

Comment: Ваш вариант верный, просто при выводе данные у вас выводится ссылка на ячейку в памяти. воспользуйтесь `Arrays.toString(Object[])` он вернет массив в `String`

Comment: Спасибо за совет, но при решении этих задач на данном этапе нам нельзя использовать вспомогательные классы....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это вовсе не ошибка, это вывод Вашего результата. Дело в том, что Java не умеет выводить массив в том виде, в котором Вы хотите. Если попытаться вывести объект массива просто через `System.out.println();`, он выводит некое описание объекта.

Во-первых, нужно из метода `split` удалить ненужный цикл, который не делает ничего.
Во-вторых, нужно сделать вывод всех полученных слов через цикл.

```
public class Main
{
    public static String[] split(String s){
        String [] array = s.split(" ");
        return array;
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hello World");
        
        String s = "I am learning java";
        
        // Сохраняем результат разделения
        String[] words = split(s);
        // Перебираем каждый элемент массива 
        for(String word : words) {
            System.out.println(word);
        }
    }
}
```

UPD:
Чтобы решение удовлетворяло условию того, что может быть несколько пробелов подряд нужно отфильтровать то, что вернёт метод `String.split()`, так как, при разделении по пробелам строки, содержащей множество пробелов, она вернёт массив, где будут тоже пробелы.

Приведу следующее решение. нужно импортировать пакет `import java.util.*;`
Далее, то, что возвращает метод `s.split(" ")` приводим к листу и этот лист фильтруем, посредством вызова метода `filter((x -> !x.isEmpty())`, что означает, вернуть только не пустые элементы списка (листа). Далее уже приводим результат к массиву строк `toArray(String[]::new)` и этот результат уже возвращаем.

```
import java.util.*;

public class Main
{
    public static String[] split(String s){
        List<String> words = Arrays.asList(s.split(" "));
        String[] filtered = words.stream().filter((x -> !x.isEmpty())).toArray(String[]::new);
        return filtered;
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hello World");
        
        String s = "I am learning   java    many     spaces";
        
        // Сохраняем результат разделения
        String[] words = split(s);
        // Перебираем каждый элемент массива 
        for(String word : words) {
            System.out.println(word);
        }
    }
}
```

Теперь даже на строку с множеством пробелом между словами `"I am learning   java    many     spaces"` он вернёт массив строк, который содержит только отдельные слова.

Более тривиальное решение, без использования лямбда-функциий, но с использованием коллекций, а конкретнее, ArrayList - динамического массива.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Main
{
    public static String[] split(String s){
        // сначала разделяем по пробелу и получаем массив
        String[] splitted = s.split(" ");
        // Далее, создаём пустой лист
        ArrayList<String> words = new ArrayList<String>();
        
        for (String row : splitted) {
            // проверяем каждое значение, не пустое ли оно и сохраняем только слова
            if (!row.isEmpty()) words.add(row);
        }
        
        String[] result = new String[words.size()];
        words.toArray(result);
        
        return result;
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hello World");
        
        String s = "I am learning   java    many     spaces";
        
        // Сохраняем результат разделения
        String[] words = split(s);
        // Перебираем каждый элемент массива 
        for(String word : words) {
            System.out.println(word);
        }
    }
}
```

Ну и в итоге - самое примитивное решение, без использования сложных методов, коллекций и лямбда-выражений, но с лишними циклами и дейсвтиями по подсчёту слов.

```
public class Main
{
    public static String[] split(String s){
        String[] splitted = s.split(" ");
        int wordsNumber = 0;
        
        for (String row : splitted) {
            // Подсчитываем сколько слов, без учёта пробелов
            if (!row.isEmpty()) wordsNumber++;
        }
        String[] words = new String[wordsNumber];
        int i = 0;
        for (String row : splitted) {
            // Теперь их сохраняем в массив слов
            if (!row.isEmpty()) {
                words[i] = row;
                i++;
            }
        }
        
        return words;
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hello World");
        
        String s = "I am learning   java    many     spaces";
        
        // Сохраняем результат разделения
        String[] words = split(s);
        // Перебираем каждый элемент массива 
        for(String word : words) {
            System.out.println(word);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Ничего себе,  функция и правда еще и проще... спасибо))  единственное класс main  сейчас разберу для себя...

Comment: на платформе куда отправила задачу выдало мне ошибку:

Comment: Ожидаемый результат:
result = [ "test" ];
Результат вашего решения:
result = [ "", "", "", "test" ];

Comment: убираю пробел с кавычками - подчеркивает красным в Idee

Comment: если убираю пробел получается вот такой вариант: Входные данные:
s = "Hello ITman";
Ожидаемый результат:
result = [ "Hello", "ITman" ];
Результат вашего решения:
result = [ "H", "e", "l", "l", "o", " ", "I", "T", "m", "a", "n" ];

Comment: @ЕкатеринаШирвель, во-первых, я исправил Ваше решение, а оно не удовлетворяет всем условиям задачи. Вам нужно учесть, что могут быть несколько пробелов подряд. А по остальным вопросам - изучите как работает метод String.split()

Comment: @ЕкатеринаШирвель, дополнил ответ, решение не особо тривиальное, особенно для новичка, но так оно работает при Ваших условиях к задаче

Comment: Спасибо....)) еще мы не проходим это и понять сложно. Но у меня дополнительный вопрос: подскажите а как я правильно могу применить в методе  split такой параметр как  limit

Comment: По условию моей задачи Между словами может стоять больше одного пробела, сколько не определено, значит количество слов не может превышать максимальную длину строки.. я так понимаю... )) ставлю  String [] array = s.split(" ", s.Lenght()) -  не верно...  и вот здесь мне не понятно.... потому что именно в этом ошибка скорее всего...

Comment: На этапе решения этих задач нам нельзя импортировать дополнительные классы или библиотеки....

Comment: @ЕкатеринаШирвель, добавил для Вас ещё решения. Самое последнее - самое тривиальное, без испортирования дополнительных библиотек. Только массивы, переменные и циклы.

Comment: Огромное спасибо) возможно именно это - то что мне нужно. Сейчас буду разбираться.

Comment: Задачу я конечно отправила, но боюсь, что разбираться в ней буду сегодня весь вечер... Алгоритм решения для меня. как для новичка еще пока сложный. Но Вам огромное при-огромное спасибо !!!! Надеюсь. что когда-нибудь и я буду кому-то полезна ))))

Comment: Разумеется нужно долго изучать и разбираться. Успехов Вам!

Comment: Sergey K. Если Вас не затруднит вот эту запись кода: if (!row.isEmpty()) wordNumber++; как можно представить проще или хотя бы расшифровать словами..... комментарий я вижу в коде, но я хочу попытаться прочитать эту запись, чтобы понять ее смысл

Comment: Есть переменная wordNumber. Это фактическое количество слов и нам нужно его вычислить. Для этого проходим по всех элеентам массива, который вернул `s.split(" ")`, а там содержатся и пустые строки, и проверяем, если это не пустая строка, то увеличиваем счётчик слов. Потом передаём это число новому массиву в качестве размера.